# Javascript alert() after Response.Redirect

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am calling this in my code behind:

```
(test.aspx)
Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
```

I want to include a javascript alert after/before being redirected to Default.aspx, is it possible?
I'm doing this because I'm passing a value to another page (test.aspx) and that page checks the db, if reader HasRow(), then redirect to Default.aspx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to do that is display the alert with javascript and then do the redirect with javascript as well:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(),"Redit","alert('asdf'); window.location='" + Request.ApplicationPath + "Default.aspx';",true);
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put the apostrophe ' where you assign the window.location, have a look at the change in the answer

Comment: It should, I've just tested it on my side and it is working, please can you paste your code to see why it's not working.

Comment: using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    buList.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                }
            }
            else
            {
              //  Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Redit", "alert('asdf'); window.location='" + Request.ApplicationPath + "Default.aspx';", true);


            }
        }

Comment: Have you made sure that it's stepping to that line? Also, is javascript enabled on your browser?

Comment: I've tested your code on my side as well and it should work, please make sure that it does actually execute the line, i.e. that your dr does not return any rows so that it will fall through to the else statement

Answer (score 4):

Lets take a look at what happens when you call response.redirect()

1. Servers sends HTTP response 302 to browser including the url to navigate to
2. browser doesn't display content of response and instead gets the content from the url specified
3. if the request to the new url succeeds, then it is displayed.

Now looking at this, we can deduce that it is impossible to tell the browser to do a alert() from the **page that issues the redirect** because its content (if any) is discarded.

It is possible to accomplish what you want from the page that you are **redirecting to**. To do this, just check Request.UrlReferrer to check if you were redirected from the correct page, then display the alert when appropriate.

example:

1. Page1 redirects to page2
2. Page2 check if Request.UrlReferrer is equal to page1
3. If equal, display alert
4. If not, do nothing special

Another approach is do the alert first then do the redirect from javascript. window.location.href = newurl.

Comment: thanks for the info mate. how do i call javascript from code behind?

Comment: @Pod You could use Page.RegisterStartupScript(). it takes in two string parameters. the first is just a unique identifier, second is you script.

Answer (score 0):

if you have display something message on Defaul.aspx page you must declare it. Because when you use redirect your page is rendering from top. You must set before redirect Sesion state on something flag and on Default.aspx page you must insert section who been added when this Sesion state been set.