# how to show message box in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm using C# to create a website and I'm trying to show a message box.  I'm trying to use JavaScript for this situation and it runs if I do the following:

```
Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert('Login Successful')</script>");
```

However if instead I do this:

```
Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert('Login Successful')</script>");    
Response.Redirect("~/admin.aspx");
```

The message box doesn't get shown.

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: I think your problem is that you do not understand how the client/server relationship works, and in particular how the server tells the client browser to execute redirects. I would suggest taking some time to study how the http protocol and web browsers in general work, then revisit your question. At that point, the problem will be obvious.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054281/javascript-alert-after-response-redirect

Comment: **You can try this:**

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199207/message-box-in-asp-net-web-application][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199207/message-box-in-asp-net-web-application

Answer (score 6):

By doing a Response.Redirect right after you're actually sending a 302 redirect to the client, so the alert is never actually being rendered in the user's browser.  Instead, try something like this

```
    Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert('Login Successful');document.location='" + ResolveClientUrl("~/admin.aspx") +"';</script>");
```

Comment: OK thanks for all support, I think I have some lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Response.Redirect` call will fire and redirect the browser before the `alert` has been shown to the user.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript written to the Response is not running because of the following line:

```
Response.Redirect("~/admin.aspx");
```

This is redirecting the response from the current page to Admin.aspx. Any further content written to the response will not be rendered and executed because the browser is being instructed to navigate to the new location.

Answer (score 1):

```
"<script language='javascript'>alert(\"" + "Your Message" + "\")</script>";
```

EDIT:

Generally, we use to show a message box in asp.net by writing a common method with message as parameter to it like follows.

```
public void UserMsgBox(string sMsg)
{
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        System.Web.UI.Control oFormObject = null;
        sMsg = sMsg.Replace("'", "\\'");
        sMsg = sMsg.Replace(Strings.Chr(34), "\\" + Strings.Chr(34));
        sMsg = sMsg.Replace(Constants.vbCrLf, "\\n");
        sMsg = "<script language='javascript'>alert(\"" + sMsg + "\")</script>";
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(sMsg);
        foreach (System.Web.UI.Control oFormObject_loopVariable in this.Controls) {
            oFormObject = oFormObject_loopVariable;
            if (oFormObject is HtmlForm) {
                break; // TODO: might not be correct. Was : Exit For
            }
        }
        oFormObject.Controls.AddAt(oFormObject.Controls.Count, new LiteralControl(sb.ToString()));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya, we can use like that also. Put if its a public method then simply by calling and passing the argument as our string will show a Messagebox to user.

Comment: I Understand but i ment actually using a scriptmanager rather than finding the form control and adding a control yourself as you do now

Comment: Ok, I just posted it and according to his requirement he will use it.

Comment: No problem, i was just curious if you had any particular reason for avoiding the ScriptManager here

Answer (score 1):

use

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "fnCall", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Login Successful! ');</script>")

 Response.Redirect("~/admin.aspx");
```

hope that helped

Answer (score 1):

Also for register a Script from a UpdatePanel you should use this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), script, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I also used  this way but code project in better way offered

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    ClientScriptManager CSM = Page.ClientScript;
    if (!ReturnValue())
    {
        string strconfirm = "<script>if(!window.confirm('Are you sure?')){window.location.href='Default.aspx'}</script>";
        CSM.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Confirm", strconfirm, false);
    }
}
     bool ReturnValue()
     {
       return false;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is late but this is the right answer as there are no answers below that you have checked, you cannot use response redirect as it will redirect the page before you can show the message box in which is appended in the end of the page. you should use the window location method:

```
Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.alert('Login Successful.');window.location='admin.aspx';</script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your .cs page to show message box if you are using update panel

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('Type here your message...')", true);
```

or

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.ControlID, this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('Type here your message')", true);
```

or this code to show message box if you are not using update panel

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('Type here your message')", true);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is an example program in which you can call your own message into message box .It's work great for you . You must try my example

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Sum Of Digit")
            {
                string a = tbInput.Text;
                int sum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
                {
                    sum = sum + Convert.ToInt32(a[i].ToString());
                }
                lblResult.Text = sum.ToString();
            }
            else if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "InterChange Number")
            {
                string interchange = tbInput.Text;
                string result = "";
                int condition = Convert.ToInt32(interchange.ToString());
                if (condition <= 99)
                {

                    result = interchange[interchange.Length - 1].ToString() + interchange[0].ToString();
                    lblResult.Text = result.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    MyMessageBox("Number Must Be Less Than 99");
                }
            }
            else if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Sum Of First n last Digit")
            {
                //example
            }
            else
            {
                MyMessageBox("Not Found");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

           MyMessageBox(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    public void MyMessageBox(string text)
    {
        string script = "alert('"+text+"');";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScripts", script, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: this isn't even closely related to the question presented