# Delete record using Confirmation box

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

In gridview if user click delete button i want to delete that record
so after clicking delete button i want to show confirmation box not alert box and from confirmation box i want to check if user click yes then delete the record else cancel
I want how to check if user click yes or no from confirm box

```
HyperLink hypComplaintMasterDelete =HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("hypComplaintMasterDelete");
hypComplaintMasterDelete.NavigateUrl = string.Format("{0}?control=CommitteeMembersDetails&Mode=De&id={1}", MasterDataHelper.NAVIGATE_Committee, lblCollagecommitteeUsersID.Text);
hypComplaintMasterDelete.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Are you sure \n You want to delete);");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to show message box in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836197/how-to-show-message-box-in-asp-net)

Comment: don't want alert box want confirmation box and according to selection perform action

Comment: See Ali Sarshogh's answer, if that isn't what you wanted, please update your question to include your research effort. that was about the second link in a search for "messagebox asp.net"

Comment: Let me tell what i want to do
In gridview if user click delete button i want to delete that record
so after clicking delete button i want to show confirmation box not alert box and from confirmation box i want to check if user click yes then delete the record else cancel
I want how to check if user click yes or no from confirm box

Comment: See Ali Sarshogh's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `GridView` place an `ImageButton` and pass the Record ID in `CommandArgument`. On `OnClientClick` call a `JS function` with `confirm`. If it will return `true` `OnClick` event will fire else nothing will happen.

ASPX

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgDelete" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'     
AlternateText="Delete" ImageUrl="YourImagePath" OnClick="imgDelete_Click" 
OnClientClick="return checkDelete()" />
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkDelete() {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete ?')) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```